# Business layer multi-tenant architecture

Tags: architecture

Building a multi tenant web application. At the moment, it is only exposed through ASP MVC Web API.
I need a consistent way of support multitenancy so that users can access only data in their: companies, departments, groups. But i want to implement that in business layer and not use Web API routing authentication since tomorrow i might expose the application through other interfaces.

So, what is the approach to implement it in business layer?

thanks!

PS.
i have a single DB for all tenants.

Comment: have you found a solution to this? elsewhere, maybe?

Comment: yes. in short, you need your own custom set of rules who (through roles, for example) can do what plus you need to set ownerId reference in your db entities. Then, for example you have a rule: regular user can edit only his own data, department admin can edit data of all users in his department, company admin in all in his company. You put those authorization checking methods into your service layer and use it at the begining of your crontroller action. Hope that helps

Comment: Hello,
I have a similar problem, but relative to cache management. We have different BDs per client, but at the cache management level in business I can not separate the data of each client. Did you have a similar problem, what solutions did you use?